# Problema ao renomear coluna em tabela do Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Precisei renomear uma coluna de uma tabela no Sql Server e usei a stored procedure de sistema SP_RENAME.

Usei da seguinte forma:

```
USE [meu_db]
GO

EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[minhaTabela].[minhaColunaAntiga]', '[minhaColunaNova]', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

Ou seja, tentei mudar o nome de 'minhaColunaAntiga' para 'minhaColunaNova', mas da forma que coloquei, a sp_rename considerou literal os caracteres '[' e ']' e a coluna passou a se chamar '[minhaColunaNova]' em vez de 'minhaColunaNova'.

Agora estou tentando corrigir isso assim:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[minhaTabela].[minhaColunaNova]', 'minhaColunaNova', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

Mas não funcionou.

Tentei também:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[minhaTabela].[[minhaColunaNova]]', 'minhaColunaNova', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

Mas também não funcionou. Tentei até com 3 '[]' e também não funcionou.

Alguém teria uma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer retirar os colchetes do nome da coluna. Para remover  os colchetes do nome da coluna é só inserir aspas antes do primeiro colchete e depois do último colchete.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
EXEC sp_rename '"[minhaColunaNova]"', 'minhaColunaNova';
```

Referência:
[How to rename something in SQL Server that has square brackets in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169214/10508872)

Comment: Funcionou, usei assim: `EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.minhaTabela."[minhaColunaNova]"', 'minhaColunaNova', 'COLUMN';
GO`. Obrigado Foca.

Answer (score 1):

Só remova as chaves da sua primeira chamada:

```
USE meu_db
GO

EXEC sp_rename 'minhaTabela.minhaColunaAntiga', 'minhaColunaNova', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

> [`SP_RENAME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Altera o nome de um objeto criado pelo usuário no banco de dados atual. Esse objeto pode ser uma tabela, índice, coluna, dados de tipo de alias, ou Microsoft .NET Framework definida pelo usuário tipo do common language runtime (CLR).
>
> [`SP_RENAME` - B. Renomeando uma coluna](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-renaming-a-column)
>
> ```
> USE AdventureWorks2012;  
> GO  
> EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID', 'TerrID', 'COLUMN';  
> GO
> ```

Comment: Entendo Sorack, mas já executei o código e a coluna agora se chama '[minhaColunaNova]', com os caracteres '[]'. Portanto preciso renomear de '[minhaColunaNova]' para 'minhaColunaNova'. Sacou?

Comment: @MarcosTulio não se usa [] em nomes de colunas

Comment: Sim, descobri isso agora. Serviu de aprendizado. Valeu.